# Trying to get the blue crosses plus the vertical lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I reproduce this?
[image]

I tried this but it does not seem to work

```
\addplot +[raw gnuplot, thick, red, mark=none, smooth] to mark=x,mark options={draw=blue}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
X Y
2007 19348
2008 23457
2009 32624
2010 34270
2011 46888
2012 45224
2013 53556
2014 55007
2015 49664
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend pos=outer north east,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},
    legend cell align=left
]
\addplot [only marks, mark = *] table {data.dat};
\addlegendentry{Data}

\addplot +[raw gnuplot, thick, red, mark=none, smooth] gnuplot {
    FIT_LIMIT=1.e-14;
    f(x)=a*x+b;
    fit f(x) 'data.dat' using 1:2 via a,b;
    % Next, plot the function using the x positions from the table
    plot 'data.dat' using 1:(f($1))
    set print "parameters.dat"; % Open a file to save the parameters into$
    print a,b;
       };     
\addlegendentry[]{\pgfplotstableread{parameters.dat}\parameters% Open the file Gnuplot wrote
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\parameters \edef\paramA{\pgfplotsretval}% Get first element, save into \paramA
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{1}\of\parameters \edef\paramB{\pgfplotsretval}% Get second element, save into \paramB
     $\pgfmathprintnumber{\paramA} x \pgfmathprintnumber{\paramB}$    
}  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a full solution: I'm unable to use correctly the `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`.
I remove the gnuplot part, using only pgf functionalities.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
    X Y
    2007 19348
    2008 23457
    2009 32624
    2010 34270
    2011 46888
    2012 45224
    2013 53556
    2014 55007
    2015 49664
\end{filecontents*}
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\tabledata
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\tabledata}
\pgfmathsetmacro\numberofrows{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',]
    \begin{axis}[
    legend pos=outer north east,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},
    legend cell align=left
    ]
    \addplot [only marks, mark = *] table {\tabledata};
    \addlegendentry{Data}
    
    \addplot table [mark=none,
    x=X,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {\tabledata};
    \addlegendentry{%
        $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
        \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\numberofrows}{% draw only the last one…
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu} % because of "too large dimension" error
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{X}\of\tabledata
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\pgfplotsretval}
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Y}\of\tabledata
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{\pgfplotsretval}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\z{\pgfplotstableregressiona*\x+\pgfplotstableregressionb}%
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        \draw [->] (axis cs:\x, \y) -- (axis cs:\x, \z);%
    }
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```